# Show homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

> Show $\mathbb N$ with topology $\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, \{5, 6\}, \{7, 8\}, \ldots$ and all unions of these, and $\mathbb N$ with topology $\{1, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{5, 7\}, \{6, 8\}, \{9, 11\}, \{10, 12\}, \ldots$ and all unions of these are homeomorphic(if they are).

I think the rule below discribes the permutation $1 \to 1, 2 \to 3, 3 \to 2, 4 \to 4, \ldots$

$f(x) = \cases{x \text{ if }x \pmod 4 = 0 \text{ or } 1 \\ x + 1 \text{ if } x \pmod 4 = 2 \\ x - 1 \text{ if } x \pmod 4 = 3}$

The inverse looks exactly the same just reading off of the given topology:

$f^{-1}(y) = \cases{y \text{ if }y \pmod 4 = 0 \text{ or } 1 \\ y + 1 \text{ if } y \pmod 4 = 2 \\ y - 1 \text{ if } y \pmod 4 = 3}$

But I am not sure how to show $f^{-1}$defined as above is the right one

For example, if $f(x) = x + 1, f^{-1}(y) = y+ 1$, then $f(f^{-1}(y)) = f(y + 1) = y + 1$ and $f^{-1}(f(x)) = f^{-1}(x + 1) = x + 1$, so no identity there. How do I show $f \circ f^{-1} = \text{identity}$ so that $f$ is bijection?

Now suppose $O$ is in the given topology of the codomain of $f$. Then $O \subset \mathbb N.$ But then $f^{-1}(O) \subset \mathbb N$ and all the elements in $f^{-1}(O)$ are subject to the rule $f^{-1}(y)$ meaning $f^{-1}(O)$ is in the given topology of the domain of $f$ implying it is open and so $f$ is continuous. Similar argument shows $f^{-1}$ is continuous. Does this part make sense? If not, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote "For example, if $f(x)=x+1$,$f^{−1}(y)=y+1$, ...", but that's not the definition of $f$.

You defined $f(x)=x+1$ **when** $x \equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

So, in the case that $x \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ we have $f^{-1}(f(x)) = f^{-1}(x+1)$

Now you need to evaluate $f^{-1}$ at $x+1$. Since $x \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ then $x+1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, so the **last** case of the definition of $f^{-1}$ applies and we have $f^{-1}(f(x)) = f^{-1}(x+1) = (x+1)-1 = x$.

Of course, you'll need to check the other cases to verify that your definition of $f^{-1}$ is correct.